# "Heterozygotic expection" - when heterozygote differs from both homozygotes, but homozygotes are similar

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, population-genetics

For simple 2-alleles genetic model {a,A} and corresponding quantitative trait Q is typically true that

*Q(aa)>=Q(aA)>=Q(AA)*

or conversely

*Q(AA)>=Q(aA)>=Q(aA).*

For example, dominance means that *Q(aa) < Q(aA)=Q(AA)* , recesivity *Q(aa)=Q(aA) < Q(AA)* ; in additive models *Q(aa) < Q(aA) < Q(AA)* etc.

The situation when *Q(aA)>Q(aa)~Q(AA)* is atypical in biology ("heterozygotic expection ?", "uncooperative alleles ?"). Known example is HBB gene (heterozygotic form gives resistence to malaria but homozygotic mutation form is sickle-cell anaemia). But this is weak example only, because f is evolutionary advantage, not a measurable  phenotypical or biochemical trait.

QUESTION 1: Are there any systematic reviews about this atypical phenomena? (about "heterozygotic expection")

QUESTION 2: Is there a standard scientific term for this phenomena?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is a bit unclear, and I think there might be a couple of mistakes in your inequalities. However, I think you are looking for the terms [*Overdominance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdominance) (also called *Heterozygote advantage*) and [*Heterosis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterosis) (also *Hybrid vigor*). Both of these concepts imply that heterozygotes and/or hybrids have a phenotype that lies outside of the range described by the homozygotes (or, for heterosis, either parent or parent population).

Here is a section from ["*Genetic Dominance: Genotype-Phenotype Relationships*"](http://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/genetic-dominance-genotype-phenotype-relationships-489) from Nature education - Scitable, which has a bit more information and a couple of references:

> In particular, the phenomenon known as **overdominance** occurs when a heterozygote has a more extreme phenotype than that of either of its parents. Indeed, in a few examples, a trait that shows overdominance sometimes confers a survival advantage in the heterozygote (Parsons & Bodmer, 1961).

You will find more information about overdominance and heterosis in any textbook on evolutionary biology, e.g. Futuyma's [Evolution](http://www.sinauer.com/evolution-853.html). There are also lots of relevant papers on the subject, and this one might be a nice example and starting point:

[Frascaroli et al. 2007. Classical Genetic and Quantitative Trait Loci Analyses of Heterosis in a Maize Hybrid Between Two Elite Inbred Lines. *Genetics* 176(1): 625-644](http://genetics.org/content/176/1/625).